# Grid like data querying in database

Tags: database, grid

I have a set of girds in my database, each grid consist of four points and each point have the coordinate of (x,y), while each grid can be located by its row and col.

To avoid the redundant of the points in the db, I save just the coordinate of the point at the bottom,left in the gird, like this:

[image]

Now for a given point with coordinate(x1,y1) I have to find the grid which the point reside in, that's to say find a gird say it is `g` that

```
g.left <= x1 <= g.right && g.bottom <=y1 <= g.top
```

Since the grids are continuous(excluding the grids at the edge), so the  question is changed to:

```
g.left <= x1 <= top_right_grid.left && g.bottom <= y1 <= top_right_grid.bottom
```

Where the `top_right_grid` have to meet this:

`top_right_grid.col  - g.col = 1,  and top_right_grid.row - g.row = 1`

So I use this to find the result:

```
SELECT g.*, top_right_grid.left,top_right_grid.bottom
FROM gis_grid g,gis_grid gd1
WHERE   top_right_grid.row - g.row =1 AND 
        top_right_grid.col - g.col =1 AND 
        g.left <=x1 AND 
        top_right_grid.left >= x1 AND 
        g.bottom/1e8 <= y1 AND 
        top_right_grid.bottom/1e8 >= y1;
```

However I meet a problems now, for the point `p1`, I will get one gird which is right, but for point `p3`, there should be two grids meet the requirement, but I got only one. For point `p2`, I can not get the result, since the `top_right_grid` does not exist in the database.

So I wonder if there is any better idea for modeling this kind of data, or make the querying as fast as possible?

Comment: Why is it that you need to reference four coordinates to get a point in a cartesian system? Wouldnt it be enough to search for g.left = x1 && g.bottom =y1 ?

Comment: There points which consist of the grid are just part of all the points.